# pass None or String value from variable to string formatting python

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, string-formatting, nonetype

I'm trying to construct query for insert data to postgreSQL. I use string formatting for passing variables to query. The thing is that value in variables may be None (returned from function).
My query looks like

```
"INSERT INTO Order (uuid) VALUES ('{}'); "
"INSERT INTO MyTable (uuid, name, uuidOtherTable) "
"VALUES ('{}', '{}', {} );".format(obj.uuid, obj.uuid, obj.name, obj.uuidOtherTable)
```

The foreign key `uuidOtherTable` may be `NULL` value, so there are variants if it exists or not.
This case is not only for the foreign keys, but the other fields too.
I would like to implement flexible version.
I am joining several insertions so `.format()` method is preferable.

When obj.uuidOtherTable is None {} works fine, but in case it string -> I have to use '{}' instead of {}.

Seems obvious but no success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use string interpolation to build SQL queries due to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

You should be using a parameterized query:

```
db_cursor_object.execute('''INSERT INTO MyTable (uuid, name, uuidOtherTable)
                            VALUES (%s, %s, %s)''', (obj.uuid, obj.name, obj.uuidOtherTable))
```

Even if the arguments don't come from user input, this is easier because it handles types automatically (eg using `''` for strings, `null` (or whatever your DB flavor is using) for `None`, etc).

Comment: Yes, I used this approach... Now I have to join multiple insertions for executing them at once, not per row. Will you please give me an idea the way to concatenate the parameterized queries ?

Comment: I've tested in DataGRIP my concantenated query with filled values, it works. I would like to execute one big query in one transaction. I've edited my query in question for you to understand my approach

Answer (score 0):

I propose You to use SQLAlchemy to work with database https://www.compose.com/articles/using-postgresql-through-sqlalchemy/ ORM makes your work easier and you don't need care to much about sql injection and properly format data into sql statement.

Comment: Thank you for advice! I have a little experience with SQLAlchemy. I hope there is a solution without  SQLAlchemy

Comment: Small experience is good opportunity to improve your skills :) In real job sql alchemy knowledge is very useful :) Good luck!